# Bread::Board service B depends on accessor on service A object

Tags: perl, inversion-of-control, moose, bread-board

Using [Bread::Board](https://metacpan.org/module/Bread%3a%3aBoard) I have an object/service `A` with with accessor `$A->foo`. Object/service B depends on `$A->Foo` for it's contstructor. How would I do this? Here's an example of what I have

```
use Moose;
use Bread::Board;


has info => ( is => 'ro', lazy => 1, isa => 'Str', default => sub { 'something' } );
extends 'Bread::Board::Container';

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    container $self => as {
        service info => $self->info;

        service A => (
             class => 'A',
             dependencies => {
                 info => depends_on('info'),
             },
        );
        service B => (
            class => 'B',
            dependencies => {
                foo => depends_on('foo'), # foo could be gotten by
            },                            # ->resolve( service => 'A' )->foo 
        );                                # e.g foo is an accessor on A
    };   
}
```

I am not sure what code I could add or should have to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've found so far is to add another service using block for just that accessor

```
use Moose;
use Bread::Board;


has info => ( is => 'ro', lazy => 1, isa => 'Str', default => sub { 'something' } );
extends 'Bread::Board::Container';

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    container $self => as {
        service info => $self->info;

        service A => (
             class => 'A',
             dependencies => {
                 info => depends_on('info'),
             },
        );
        service B => (
            class => 'B',
            dependencies => {
                foo => depends_on('foo'), # foo could be gotten by
            },                            # ->resolve( service => 'A' )->foo 
        );                                # e.g foo is an accessor on A

# ADD SERVICE
        service foo => (
            block => sub {
               my $s = shift;
               return $s->param('A')->foo;
            },
            dependencies => [ 'A' ],
        );
    };   
}
```

This of course all assumes that A has an accessor foo